# Trouble displaying digits in JPanels with in a Digital Clock

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a digital clock project where I am to make a clock that looks like this:

[image: digital clock]

There are 9 panels in the one frame.  One panel of the `TitlePanel` class, 6 of the `DigitPanel` class, and 2 of the `ColonPanel` class.  The problem I am having is with the `DigitPanel` class.  I have this thing basically done but when I execute the program, the `setDigit` method for some reason does not overwrite the default value of digit.

Can someone please show me what's wrong with the methods I have for the `DigitPanel` class?

**Main class:**

```
public class DigitPane extends JPanel {

    DigitPanel[] hourDigit = new DigitPanel[]{new DigitPanel(), new DigitPanel()};
    DigitPanel[] minDigit = new DigitPanel[]{new DigitPanel(), new DigitPanel()};
    DigitPanel[] secDigit = new DigitPanel[]{new DigitPanel(), new DigitPanel()};
    private String hour = pad(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR));
    private String min = pad(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    private String sec = pad(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND));
    private char[] hours = hour.toCharArray();
    private char[] minutes = min.toCharArray();
    private char[] seconds = sec.toCharArray();

    public DigitPane() {
        JPanel digitsPanel = new JPanel();
        digitsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(digitsPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        digitsPanel.setSize(new Dimension(605, 100));

        digitsPanel.add(new panelPadding());

        hourDigit[0].setDigit(hours[0]);
        digitsPanel.add(hourDigit[0]);
        digitsPanel.add(new panelPadding());

        hourDigit[1].setDigit(hours[1]);
        digitsPanel.add(hourDigit[1]);
        digitsPanel.add(new panelPadding());

        digitsPanel.add(new ColonPanel());
        digitsPanel.add(new panelPadding());

        minDigit[0].setDigit(minutes[0]);
        digitsPanel.add(minDigit[0]);
        digitsPanel.add(new panelPadding());

        minDigit[1].setDigit(minutes[1]);
        digitsPanel.add(minDigit[1]);
        digitsPanel.add(new panelPadding());

        digitsPanel.add(new ColonPanel());
        digitsPanel.add(new panelPadding());

        secDigit[0].setDigit(seconds[0]);
        digitsPanel.add(secDigit[0]);
        digitsPanel.add(new panelPadding());

        secDigit[1].setDigit(seconds[1]);
        digitsPanel.add(secDigit[1]);
        digitsPanel.add(new panelPadding());

        this.add(digitsPanel);
    }

    protected String pad(int value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(value));
        while (sb.length() < 2) {
            sb.insert(0, "0");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DigitalTimeUI();
    }

    public class panelPadding extends JPanel {

        public panelPadding() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5, 80));
        }
    }
}
```

**TitlePanel:**

```
public class TitlePanel extends JPanel {

    JLabel title;

    public TitlePanel() {
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(605, 100));
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        title = new JLabel("DIGITAL CLOCK");
        title.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 72));
        title.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        this.add(title);
    }
}
```

**DigitPanel:**

```
public class DigitPanel extends JPanel {

    private char digit = '0';

    public DigitPanel() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(String.valueOf(digit));
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 72));
        label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.add(label);
    }

    public final char getDigit() {
        return digit;
    }

    public void setDigit(char digit) {
        this.digit = digit;
    }
}
```

Comment: In `setDigit` you are just changing value of `digit` instance variable, this will not gonna change value in JLabel. As a simple solution you need to manually change text of JLabel, which should also be a global variable for this class, in this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `JLabel` in `DigitPanel` should be a class level variable.
2. `setDigit` should set the label's text property

.

```
public class DigitPanel extends JPanel {

    private JLabel label = new JLabel(String.valueOf(digit));

    public DigitPanel() {
        label = new JLabel(String.valueOf(0));
        label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 72));
        label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.add(label);
    }

    public final char getDigit() {
        return label.getText().charAt(0);
    }

    public void setDigit(char digit) {
        label.setText(Character.toString(digit);
    }
}
```

Comment: It has something to do with the ordered list.  Thanks though :D

Comment: I think you meant `Character.toString(digit)` and you removed the `private char digit`, but it worked! Thanks!

Comment: @DarthCthulhu Thanks!  Updated by hand :P.  I removed the `digit` because I can't see a reason for it.  You can set/get the value directly from the `label`.